# If I run an http server in my user account (linux cluster) how to enable other users to access it?

Tags: python, linux, http, server

I want to deploy a flask app with http.server (ngnix not installed by admin). I want any user who logs into the cluster to access it. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Will it actually work? Depends on missing details of your cluster's network setup. Is it on-topic here? Definitely not. Did you actually try it before asking? Signs point to "no".

Comment: Two issues: I can effectively try it only by asking someone to check. I have implemented it. Works for me but need another user to try it. Secondly, I am a new employee. Want to make sure this is not a trivial question.

Comment: You just need to ask another user to try it, then. There's no _general_ problem with doing this, but there could be potential problems hiding in the details of your cluster setup, which we don't know. I'm not going to try and generate a comprehensive list of ways this could fail due to network or SELinux setups, when it would be so much easier for you to just get someone to test it.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP server interfaces are visible to all users that are connected to a machine that has direct network access to the machine your server is running on.

If you need them to access the interface just provide the ip address and port where the server is running and the will be able to access it as users of the Flask app you are running. Just make sure you allow the users to access the needed resources.